Linear mapping with rational coefficient representing integer vectors
The following question arose from trying to understand systems of linear equations over integers. Given $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{Q})$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}^m$, how to determine if there exists $x\in\mathbb{Q}^n$ such that the vector $Ax+b$ has integer coefficients.
My attempt: We can multiply on a common denominator $d$, and obtain a linear system $dAx+db=dy$ with integer coefficients modulo $d$. The problem is, however, that the coefficients of $x$ are rational, and I don't see how to bound the denominator.
